# How can I complete 'The Fated Four' as a bow user?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

The Village quest 'The Fated Four' requires you to fight a Gammoth, an Astalos, a Mizutsune, and a Glavenus, in the Forlorn Arena.

**Using a bow, how can I finish this quest in the 50 minute time limit?**

What I've tried so far:

Hub Rank 3

Gear

- Obsidian Bow Lv.1
- Aelucanth Armor Set Lv.3 with decorations to get Expert +2
- Power/Armor charm
- MegaDemonDrug/Armor
- Energy Drinks
- Well Cooked Meats
- Flash Bombs
- Pit Trap
- Shock Trap
- 8x Tranq bombs
- 10x small bomb
- 2x large bomb+
- 3x large bomb
- 10x bounce bomb
- 10x bounce bomb+
- all arrow coatings usable by Obsidian Bow.

Palicos

- Support Palico w/ Tigrex set
- Healing Palico w/ Gore Magala set

Using Adept style.  Most shots are taken at charge lv.3, unless I'm rushed, which results in a lot of lv.2 shots until the boss settles from quick movements.

Bow doesn't seem to have any great spots against Gammoth, so I try to spend most of my bounce bombs under the body or under the head.  Consistently hitting the trunk is challenging due to the tusks.  Try to aim for the head, but he tends to spin around on his back hips quite a bit.  Support cat will put down a poison trap when he's a few hundred HP away from staggered, attempt to capture. ~15 minutes to complete.

Astalos is a bit easier, can reliably hit his head from close to mid range, so most of the spread is in one zone.  Usually break the head crest.  Support cat puts down a trap when he's close to stagger, try to trap. ~15 minutes to complete.

Mizutsune isn't terribly hard either, but the water beam can catch me off guard and wreck my stamina bar.  Head is easy to target, often break one of the ears. Don't need to trap, but can if the opportunity is there.  ~10 minutes to complete.

Glavenus is a tank and I haven't found a safe place anywhere near him.  I hang back mid to long range which makes bow damage very low.  I watch for the tail-bite tell of the spinning slash, which will often one-hit KO me.  I often aim for head and throat, as a throat shot will sometimes result in a stun if it's glowing.  Simply can't do enough damage in the time left to drop him.

Comment: You do use coatings, right? And know about critical distance?

Comment: Have you tried a bow with Rapid shots instead of Spread?

Comment: No, I have no idea what's available at that point.

Comment: If you're having trouble hunting Glavenus on its own, you should probably focus on that before trying a multi-monster quest

Comment: When I play solo I like to go for Aerial style, it gives an alternative to most weapon tactics and occasionally mount and topple the monster to setup for large attacks/ part breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Bows have a lot of nuance to them, and require particular care in order to bring out their highest damage output:

- Always make sure you're in critical distance, where the screen shakes on impact
- Try to always reach a level 3 charge, and follow up with a Power Shot whenever you can

  - Related, Focus is incredibly good as a Bow user, probably the single best skill for it
- Use Power Coatings, and bring combines for more if you run out
- If having trouble managing stamina, bring Dash Juice
- Rapid shots are significantly easier to use and hit weakspots with, they'll usually deal more damage than Spread shots
- Since your most used shot will be the level 3 charge, make sure the Bow you're using has a powerful level 3 charge shot. Some Bows may only have a Rapid 1 shot on their level 3 charge, lowering damage output.
- Learn weakspots and always aim for them

If you're still having trouble, nothing beats good old practice. Hunt the four monsters separately until you know everything there is to know about them, then try The Fated Four again.